# Bootstrap table with subtables with additional columns

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-table

I am using bootstrap table (http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/) and I have a situation where I have nested subtables. In my subtable I would have multiple rows with one additional column in each sub table. Something like below:

```
    #   |   Project     |   Number of Lines
+   1   |   ABC         |   15,000

        #   |   Project     |   Repo    |   Number Of Lines
    +   1   |   ABC         |   abc     |   1500

            #   |   Project     |   Repo    |   Language    |   Number Of Lines
            1   |   ABC         |   abc     |   java        |   1000
            2   |   ABC         |   abc     |   xml         |   500

    +   2   |   ABC         |   def     |   1440
    +   3   |   ABC         |   ghi     |   1200
    +   4   |   ABC         |   kbc     |   1700

+   2   |   DEK         |   15,000
+   3   |   TREM        |   15,000
+   4   |   BER         |   15,000
```

Do you think it's possible to have additional columns in subtables using bootstrap-table library? If so can someone please provide an example? I appreciate your help.

Thank you,
Ravi Hasija

Comment: Post some code please so it will be helpful for you as well for others

Comment: Please update this thread, either accepting an answer or providing detail via comment or edit why it doesnt answer your issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it does, as whatever you pass into detailView is whats used, so if the table you create/use there has more columns, it will show them.

Thats why there is no 'subtable' option, just `detailView` and the ability to pass or even dynamically create whatever content there you want.

http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/documentation/

---

http://issues.wenzhixin.net.cn/bootstrap-table/#options/sub-table.html

```
<div class="container">
    <h1>Sub Table</h1>
    <p>Use <code>onExpandRow</code> event to handle your detail view.</p>
    <table id="table"
           data-detail-view="true">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-field="id">ID</th>
            <th data-field="name">Item Name</th>
            <th data-field="price">Item Price</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
</div>
<script>
    var $table = $('#table');
    $(function () {
        buildTable($table, 8, 1);
    });
    function expandTable($detail, cells) {
        buildTable($detail.html('<table></table>').find('table'), cells, 1);
    }
    function buildTable($el, cells, rows) {
        var i, j, row,
                columns = [],
                data = [];
        for (i = 0; i < cells; i++) {
            columns.push({
                field: 'field' + i,
                title: 'Cell' + i,
                sortable: true
            });
        }
        for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            row = {};
            for (j = 0; j < cells; j++) {
                row['field' + j] = 'Row-' + i + '-' + j;
            }
            data.push(row);
        }
        $el.bootstrapTable({
            columns: columns,
            data: data,
            detailView: cells > 1,
            onExpandRow: function (index, row, $detail) {
                expandTable($detail, cells - 1);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

That prints off columns using indexs, doesnt pass in any data via url or other means.

But you can clearly see that `buildTable` just prints off a `<table>` and calls `bootstrapTable` init code on that new table when `OnExpandRow` is triggered, which calls `buildTable` again on next `OnExpandRow`, and ect to ad infinitum.

Whatever table you put into the `detailView` is what is used, regardless of the parent table.

Just use F12 to see the output once you expand a few rows.